# Location-based App prevents Device from Sleep mode

Tags: android, sleep, locationmanager, power-management

I wrote a location-based app using the `LocationManager.addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)` function which is perfectly what I want. But after that, on my device (Samsung Galaxy S), the app is shown on top of the battery usage view just after a few hours, having a huge period in "stay awake"-time. Before using that api, I used "`requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, PendingIntent intent)`" and the app did not appear in the battery Usage-Stat (at least not that much).

I do not start any service or any other background task/thread.

So why is that? How can I reduce the "Stay awake"-Period ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the device will try to get a fix every [4 minutes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). This must have caused the battery to have a large stay awake time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't known how i could have overread this.